# how to solve radical expression using javascript

Tags: javascript

This is my radical expression:

```
var equation1 = "\\sqrt[4]{8}"; 
var equation2 = "\\sqrt[6]{x^2}";
```

How to get answer of this using javascript.

Comment: What do these curly braces mean? More importantly, can you post your attempts at solving this problem in your question?

Comment: tha means 4 sqrt of 8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript's exponentiation function is `Math.pow(base, exponent)`, so the 4th root of 8 is `Math.pow(8, 1/4)`.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/pow?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FMath%2Fpow et al.

If you're asking how to parse those strings of yours and evaluate, that's a different thing altogether.